# How do I run a systemd oneshot service whenever my system gets a new IPv6 address?

Tags: networking, systemd, dhcp, ipv6, d-bus

I would like to run a systemd [oneshot service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) whenever my system gets a new IPv6 address assigned to it from the network router (this would be on boot, and periodically throughout its uptime).

Ideally, this event would be only for IPv6 address updates, and not include potential IPv4 address changes.

Is it possible to monitor networkd dbus activity for this kind of event with systemd?

My ultimate goal is to hit a dynamic DNS endpoint whenever this happens, so that this system's IPv6 DNS record avoids going stale.

Comment: Is the IPv6 addressing via SLAAC, or DHCPDv6? Because SLAAC addresses are not showing up in the output of a `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` test script.

Comment: In my case SLAAC, but ideally this could cover both bases.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote something like this many years ago, called (unimaginatively) [autoddns](https://github.com/vandry/autoddns).

It doesn't call a systemd service (I don't think systemd existed at the time!) but it does call an external process to perform the DNS update ([nsupdate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nsupdate)). It does however monitor IP address additions and deletions directly at the netlink level, which means it will pick them up no matter how they happen (manual administrative configuration, SLAAC, DHCP, Network Manager). It reacts instantaneously when changes occur. It does support filters (designed for automatically excluding things like link-local addresses), so you can get it to respect IPv6 address changes and ignore IPv4 ones, as you wish to do.

Perhaps you can use it or modify it to meet your needs. Most of the magic for detecting and reacting to IP address changes is in [watchip.c](https://github.com/vandry/autoddns/blob/master/watchip.c), I think.

Comment: Looks promising!  I'll try to mess around with it, but I'm not great with c.  Perhaps a simple README would make it easier to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

Using a persistent systemd service, not oneshot:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dynamic DNS updater
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target

[Service]
Type=exec
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/ddns-updater

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

The corresponding `/usr/local/sbin/ddns-updater` daemon script, using the `ip` tool from the `iproute2` package:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

ip -o -6 monitor address |
    while read index iface proto addr dummy scope temporary dummy; do
        case "$iface:$proto:$scope:$temporary" in
            enp2s0:inet6:global:dynamic)
                addr="${addr%/*}"
                if [ "$addr" != "$current" ]; then
                    nsupdate -k /etc/network/nsupdate/Kyour.dyn.domain.name.+157+58882.private <<EOF
update delete your.dyn.domain.name AAAA
update add your.dyn.domain.name 300 AAAA $addr
send
EOF
                    echo "AAAA record set to $addr"
                    current="$addr"
                fi;;
        esac
    done
```

This avoids writing the often changing randomized (privacy-enhanced, temporary) address into the DNS server, but will act up if you have several global non-temporary addresses (like a statically configured one and a SLAAC one). Adjust as necessary (interface name, domain name, key file path, additional logic, TTL...)

Comment: After 2 days of research and trying all sort of hooks with network-dispatcher, NetworkManager, dhcp... nothing triggered after changes on the ipv6. Even after configuring correctly netplan and its renderer. But this solution is robust, elegant and works flawlessly.